# Equivalent Uses of SetDelayed Result in Different Results When Defining an Existing Variable

Tags: function-construction, expression-manipulation, parametric-functions

I have the following expression.

```
(((gt\[Phi][r]^2 + gtt[r] g\[Phi]\[Phi][r]) Derivative[1][gt\[Phi]][r] - 2 gtt[r] gt\[Phi][r] Derivative[1][g\[Phi]\[Phi]][r]))/(gtt[r] Sqrt[grr[r] (gt\[Phi][r]^2 - gtt[r] g\[Phi]\[Phi][r])])
```

I want to now replace the functions `gxx[r]` with some known expressions. I do this in two way that I believe to be equivalent but get different results. The first way is I define some expression:

```
f[r_] := -r^2/(2 \[Alpha]) (1 - Sqrt[1 + 4 \[Alpha]/r^2 (r^2/l^2 - m)]);
L = Sqrt[(2 \[Alpha])/(Sqrt[1 + (4 \[Alpha])/l^2] - 1)];
\[CapitalXi] = Sqrt[1 + a^2/L^2];
dS2[r_] = d[r]^2/f[r] + r^2/L^4 (a d[t] - \[CapitalXi] L^2 d[\[Phi]])^2 - f[r] (\[CapitalXi] d[t] - a d[\[Phi]])^2 // Expand;
dCoords = {d[t], d[r], d[\[Phi]]};
grr[r_]:= Coefficient[dS2[r], dCoords[[2]]^2] ;
gtt[r_]:= Coefficient[dS2[r], dCoords[[1]]^2] ;
g\[Phi]\[Phi][r_]:= Coefficient[dS2[r], dCoords[[3]]^2] ;
gt\[Phi][r_]:=1/2Coefficient[dS2[r], dCoords[[1]]dCoords[[3]]] ;
```

The second way is by directly defining the expressions `gxx[r]` by their explicit expressions.

```
gtt[r_] := (a^2 (r - r Sqrt[1 + (4 \[Alpha])/l^2])^2 + r^2 (1 - Sqrt[1 - (4 m \[Alpha])/r^2 + (4 \[Alpha])/l^2]) (2 \[Alpha] + a^2 (-1 + Sqrt[1 + (4 \[Alpha])/l^2])))/(4 \[Alpha]^2);
gt\[Phi][r_] := -((a r^2 (Sqrt[1 + (4 \[Alpha])/l^2] - Sqrt[1 - (4 m \[Alpha])/r^2 + (4 \[Alpha])/l^2]) Sqrt[1 + (a^2 (-1 + Sqrt[1 + (4 \[Alpha])/l^2]))/(2 \[Alpha])])/(2 \[Alpha]));
grr[r_] := (2 \[Alpha])/(r^2 (-1 + Sqrt[1 - (4 m \[Alpha])/r^2 + (4 \[Alpha])/l^2]));
g\[Phi]\[Phi][r_] := (r^2 (2 \[Alpha] + a^2 (Sqrt[1 + (4 \[Alpha])/l^2] - 
Sqrt[1 - (4 m \[Alpha])/r^2 + (4 \[Alpha])/l^2])))/(2 \[Alpha]);
```

If I compare the two way of defining the function I get that they are the same. However, the result I get for the original expression (more specifically I am interested in its limit as r->inf) is not the same i.e. the direct definition results in a finite expression, while the implicit definition with coefficients results in ComplexInfinity.

P.S. Using Set would be more appropriate here, however it does not replace the derivative of expressions (and also results in ComplexInfinity)

Comment: There are some stray backslashes in your expressions. When I remove them so that I can execute your code, I do not get the same results from version 1 and version 2. I don't know if that's because an error in your code or an error in how you posted your code, but I don't know how to proceed until you provide correct, executable code first.

Comment: @lericr Apologies, I must have messed up something during copying and reformating the code here. The two expressions should be equivalent now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The resulting expressions are complex algebraic not equivalent. The reason is that the square roots are differently expressed in the parameters.

After  defining the first and the second set of definitions, I define the functions as a set

```
g1 = {grr[r], gtt[r], g\[Phi]\[Phi][r], gt\[Phi][r]} // FullSimplify

g2 = {grr[r], gtt[r], g\[Phi]\[Phi][r], gt\[Phi][r]} // FullSimplify

You see same diffences, even if 

g1==g2//Simplify
```

The limits exhibit the differences in the square root representations of the last expression. Generally speaking limits with root expressions are multivalued and have to be done with excessive supply of conditions assuring reality.

```
Assuming[\[Alpha] > 0 && l > 0, 
 Simplify[Limit[g1^2, r -> \[Infinity]]]]

Out = {0, \[Infinity], \[Infinity], -(( a^2 l m^2 (-2 l \[Alpha] + a^2 (l - Sqrt[l^2 + 4 \[Alpha]])))/( 2 \[Alpha] (l^2 + 4 \[Alpha])))}



 Assuming[\[Alpha] > 0 && l > 0, 
 Simplify[Limit[g2^2, r -> \[Infinity]]]]

Out = {0, \[Infinity], \[Infinity], (a^2 l^2 m^2 (2 \[Alpha] + a^2 (-1 + Sqrt[1 + (4 \[Alpha])/l^2])))/(2 \[Alpha] (l^2 + 4 \[Alpha]))}
```